# How to filter out a factor in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to filter out one factor so I can plot ggplot with the rest, I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
library(ggplot2)
figvad <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/vadev.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)
figvadc <- figvad %% c(!=Pre-clinical)
```

I also used:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
figvad <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/vadev.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)
figvadclinic<-figvad %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Type") %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_detect(type, 'Pre-clinical') )
library(repr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
options(repr.plot.width=17, repr.plot.height=10)

ggplot(figvadclinic, aes(x=Phase, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 0.5) +
  coord_polar()+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), element_text(size=25, face=4L))+
theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Your second line `figvadc <- figvad %% c(!=Pre-clinical)` returns error.  In addition, I get errors in the function `Error: Column name `Type` must not be duplicated`  in the second block of code

Comment: Yes, I know @akrun, that's why I'm asking a question for help.

Comment: My doubt is that your data already have a column named 'Type' as per the read.csv'.  So, do you need to create another column 'Type'

Comment: try 
```figvadc <- figvad %>% filter(Phase != Pre-clinical)
```
not sure if this is what you want to accomplish tho

Comment: Sorry @akrun I did not mean my sentence to come out with an attitude, I do appreciate your help, I wrote it asking for help, I hate it when my sentence convey a bad attitude, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @user432797 it's okay.  I was thinking that your code was used on a different data and the data showed in the github is different.  Just wante to clarify. thanks for the reply

Comment: @user432797 that is not my line.  It is the code I copied from your post and just to show that it is not correct

Comment: Sorry @akrun, I thought you are the only one in this conversation

Comment: I just used your line and I get this error Error: Problem with filter()` input ..1.` @Ben

Comment: I forgot the quotes, `figvadc <- figvad %>% filter(Phase != "Pre-clinical")` should do

Comment: It worked flawlessly @Ben thank you so much!, I just adjusted c to C